# Sorting singly linked list by second node element. Java

Tags: java, sorting, singly-linked-list

I am trying to get a way to sort this singly linked list by the last names that have been entered into it. I thought I might try a bubble sort but I am having problems traversing the list by the second element and comparing. The list contains only 3 names right now as console entries but it should have 10 names when I am done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package LinkedList;

import java.util.*;


class SLinkedList
{

   public String data1;
   public String data2;
   public SLinkedList next;

   public SLinkedList()
   {
      data1 = "";
      data2 = "";
      next = null;
   }
   public SLinkedList(String value1, String value2)
   {
      data1 = value1;
      data2 = value2;
      next = null;
   }
   public SLinkedList InsertNext(String value1, String value2)
   {
      SLinkedList node = new SLinkedList(value1, value2);
      if(this.next == null)
      {
         // Easy to handle
         node.next = null; // already set in constructor
         this.next = node;
      }
      else
      {
         // Insert in the middle
         SLinkedList temp = this.next;
         node.next = temp;
         this.next = node;
       }
       return node;
   }


   public int DeleteNext()
   {
      if(next == null)
         return 0;
       SLinkedList node = this.next;
       this.next = this.next.next;  // can be NULL here
       node = null;
       return 1;
   }
   public void Traverse(SLinkedList node)
   {
      if(node == null)
         node = this;
      System.out.println("\nTraversing in Forward Direction\n");
      while(node != null)
      {
         System.out.println(node.data1 + " " + node.data2);
         node = node.next;
      }
   }
   public void bubbleSort(SLinkedList node) {
       if(node == null)
           node = this;
       String current;
       String second;
       String temp;
       System.out.println("Attemptint to sort...");
       while(node != null)
       {
           current = node.data2;
           node = node.next;
           second = node.data2;
           System.out.println(current + " " + second);
           if(current.compareTo(second) < 0) {

               System.out.println("greater than zero");
           }

           node = null;
           //node = node.next;

       }    
   }


      public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter names in the format of: 'Ed King' with"
              + " a single space in between.");
      firstName = sc.next();
      lastName = sc.next();
      SLinkedList node1 = new SLinkedList(firstName, lastName);
      System.out.print("Enter second name: ");
      firstName = sc.next();
      lastName = sc.next();
      SLinkedList node2 = node1.InsertNext(firstName, lastName);
      System.out.print("Enter third name: ");
      firstName = sc.next();
      lastName = sc.next();
      SLinkedList node3 = node2.InsertNext(firstName, lastName);


      node1.bubbleSort(null);

   }
}
```

Comment: I won't post an answer on this, but it would be better to use [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Your implementation of bubble sort is fundamentally wrong.  Bubble sort requires a nested loop.
- Given the way you've designed the data structure, the bubble sort method has to return the new start of list.
- Don't start method names with a capital letter.  This is Java not C#.
- If you can't visualize what your code is doing, use a debugger to single-step it and observe how the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Linkedlist should be sorted using merge sort. So chage your algo.

Coming to bubble sort implementation , your implementation is not correct[why are you not using temp at all]. You shld look to swap nodes.